# list of drag&drop actions

Tags: 16.04, mouse

Is there a place related to Ubuntu 16.04 where the possible drag&drop actions are documented?

The mouse cursor changes appearance when holding SHIFT and/or CONTROL while dragging files, but I have no idea any more what these signify. I searched the Ubuntu help (https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/index.html) but that does not mention anything.

Comment: Which application are you asking about? Is it the file manager?

Comment: A plus in the cursor is copy, an arrow is move.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not looking for an answer of the actual actions, but a webpage where this is documented. anyone?

Comment: The reason I am looking for a web reference is that the information on SO will get outdated, while the webpage (website) in question should always be up-to-date (well, reasonably).
This is a a problem I have with SO: you are supposed to answer questions with information that is permanent,  but will become worthless after a while; adding a link has the same risk, so the combination of the two is the best way,